# Respect Validating optional input array for specific fields

Tags: php, respect-validation

I have a registration input that can be used by a consumer or a fleet consumer. Depending on what they are, depends on if they send extra details about their fleet or not. A regular consumer will just send their information, where as a fleet consumer will send the same information, with 2 extra fields in a sub array.

The input data is:

```
// POST data registration
// First example, fleet
{
  "firstName" : "Mike",
  "lastName" : "Dan",
  "email" : "email@email.com",
  "password" : "rawpassword",
  "fleet" : {
    "fleetCompanyName" : "My Company",
    "driverID" : "1234567890"
  }
}

// Second example, non fleet
{
  "firstName" : "Mike",
  "lastName" : "Dan",
  "email" : "email@email.com",
  "password" : "rawpassword",
}
```

I need to validate the fleet input if it is set (Both fields need to be valid if its set), but ignore the fleet field if it is not set.

```
    # Validation
$v = v::key('firstName', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('lastName', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('email', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('password', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('fleet', v::optional(v::arrayType(),[v::key('fleetCompanyName',v::charset('ASCII')),v::key('driverID', v::intVal())]),false);
```

That's my current iteration, which allows fleet to be optional, but isn't working on validating the array correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to do it in one command, so found this solution for it:

```
$v = v::key('firstName', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('lastName', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('email', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('password', v::notEmpty())
    ->key('fleet', v::optional(v::key('fleetCompanyName', v::charset('ASCII'))), false)
    ->key('fleet', v::optional(v::key('driverID', v::intVal())), false);
```

For each sub array value I need, I would need to add another command to the chain like the above. Hope that helps anyone else.